# Is there a way to use numba with "nopython=True" and numpy / scipy / sklearn

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, numba

I'm new to numba but excited by the possibilities. I'm trying to run a least squares algorithm over each row of an N x N matrix (20964 x 20964). At each row, I have to update the "model_array," such that the row is multiplied by an external predictor.

(For what it's worth, I've also tested sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression, statsmodels.OLS, and the scipy.linalg.lstsq, but the numpy implementation appears fastest.)

So I'm basically looking to run "ppi" 20964 times, with each iteration including 20964 least squares fittings. "ppi" works fine in object mode (using "@jit"), but it takes 2.2 s per iteration. Given "dim_vox" = 20964, I'm looking to improve the speed. Included below is the inner loop that I was looking to run at each row:

```
@jit
def fit_ex(modarr, yseries):
    return np.linalg.lstsq(modarr, yseries)[0][2]

@njit
def ppi(timeseries, nvox, modarr, a):
    for j in range(nvox):
        yt = timeseries[j, :]
        a[j] = fit_ex(modarr, yt)

ts = np.loadtxt(ts_name)
dim_vox, dim_ts = ts.shape
a = np.zeros(dim_vox, dtype=np.float64)
```

and "model_array" is an n x m numpy array. 
Then running this

```
ppi(ts, dim_vox, model_array, a)
```

Gives the following error:

```
TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Internal error at <numba.typeinfer.CallConstrain object at 0x117f65290>:

File "<ipython-input-407-de1b4104525d>", line 6
```

I'm using numba 0.18.2, python 2.7.9. Apologies if I'm glossing over something obvious.

Comment: Are you expecting `numba` to rewrite and speedup `lstsq`?

Comment: Nope. To speedup the loop through nvox in "ppi."

Comment: Do you have a sense of how much time is spent with the mechanics of looping v time spent in the `lstsq` routine?  It doesn't seem to be doing much else.

Comment: Why not use all of `timeseries` in one `lstsq` call?  `np.linalg.lstsq(modarr, timeseries.T)[0].T`